# JQuery, Froala - changing CSS on element where cursor is

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

Using Froala Rich Text Editor and want to change CSS for element where the blinking cursor is in the textbox.  Have created a custom button I click to do this.  The button works to initiate the callback function, but having trouble with JQuery code:

```
callback: function () {
    $(this).addClass('big');
}
```

This does not change anything.  Using the code below changes all the 'P' elements rather than just the one where the cursor is on.

```
callback: function () {
  $('p').addClass('big');
}
```

How would I correct this code so when I move the mouse to click the button, only the element that has the blinking cursor on it changes the Class?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Inside the Froala texarea will be normal HTML, such as:

```
<p>one element</p>
<p>two element</p>
<p>three element</p>
```

WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN:
When your blinking cursor is on the last element, I click on the button to initiate the callback, and the CSS will be applied only to that last element and not the first two.

Comment: How can you have the cursor over the editor AND be clicking a button at the same time ? Do you mean that the button toggles the behavior and the mouse movement over the editor space should then apply the css on mouseover ?

Comment: When you have a textarea, you can click on an area, type something and wherever you stopped, the blinking cursor is there and stays blinking there.  You can move the mouse around and it's still there.  Just like when you work on MS Word, or any other editor - wherever you have clicked, the cursor stays there, but you can move the mouse pointer anywhere you want.

Comment: "this" references the button being clicked an "p" references all "p" elements so this functionality makes sense. I believe you are trying to reference the element where the cursor is positioned in which I think you should look into something along the lines of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good amount of searching, found the most simple answer!  On the Froala site, there is an option called "paragraphStyle.apply(value)".  Can read it [here](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/methods#paragraphStyle.apply).

The callback is then very simple:

```
callback: function () {
  this.paragraphStyle.apply('big')
}
```

"this." seems to track where the blinking cursor is and NOT where the mouse pointer is, which is what was desired.

The completed Froala code to add a button with a book symbol, which is intended to format the paragraph to a css style called 'big' is shown below.  In my case, big would be to colorize and make bigger, so the text stood out.

```
  //custom icon book quote button
  $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('quote', {NAME: 'book'});
  $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('quote', {
    title: 'quote',
    focus: true,
    undo: true,
    refreshAfterCallback: true,
    callback: function () {
        this.paragraphStyle.apply('big')
    }
  });
```

The Froala site doesn't give good examples, but just single line snippets that are hard to figure out for newbies.  Hope this helps someone!